# JavaScript get selected text of only Particular span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fetch all the selected text of one particular span,

```
 <span style="font-size:40px">Hi tTheee</span> <span style="font-size:20px">hello</span> <span style="font-size:20px">sdsds </span>
```

**I am using window.getSelection()**
If user selects **"hi tTheee hello"** that means he has selected 2 spans, But i want to fetch only Hi tTheee. How can i do this??

Comment: how user select !by selecting word by mouse!! better select box or checkbox

Comment: User selects by mouse. i am using windo .getSelection

Comment: @SamTengWong How  do that using window.getSelection()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If user selects "hi tTheee hello" that means he has selected 2 spans, But i want to fetch only Hi tTheee` 
so I understand is you want to get the first span how much user selected span

Here I used mouseup function to get user select action !!

```
$(document).on("mouseup",function(){
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  content = range.cloneContents();
  var select = content.querySelectorAll('span'); 
  console.log(select[0].innerHTML);//if u want all selected do loop
});
```

Comment: cant i get the selected span id?

Answer (score -1):

get the index of the selected spans and choose the span with the smallest index